# Call Step Function from API Gateway Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to invoke Step Function from API Gateway Lambda. I followed this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html, and Step Function does invoke. Now I want to modify serverless template to do the same thing, but I'm unable to find any good examples.

Does anyone have any info or an example of this?

Thanks!

Comment: That tutorial actually shows an API Gateway direct integration with Step Functions, not including Lambda. Here is another good example using AWS CDK: https://serverlessland.com/patterns/apigw-sfn-cdk